# Why cannot install python package by cmd

Tags: python, cmd, pip

Why cannot install by input "pip install xxxx"in cmd,
only can install by input "python -m pip install xxxx"?

//problem solved , but dont know why
[example.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq2MP.png)

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: do you get error message with `pip install` ? Show it. We can't read in your mind.

Comment: no message nor error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pip install` directly after adding `C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts` to the environment PATH variable in windows.

Note: The path `C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts` is where pip.exe is installed or present on your computer based on Pythong version.

Comment: Sure, please upvope the answer, if helped. Also, modify your question with appropriate details in case other face the same issue.